# SignalR + Web Api 2 Bearer Token Authentication

Tags: authentication, signalr, asp.net-web-api2, signalr-hub, bearer-token

I have client side app which is running on nodejs server and have Web Api project. I have Bearer Token Authentication in Startup.cs class:

```
        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        var oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthOptions);

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(newOAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

and I want to start hub on client:

```
 $.connection.hub.url = 'https://localhost:44302/signalr/hubs';
 this.proxy = $.connection.chathub;

 this.proxy.client.onMessage = function (stock){
    };
       $.connection.hub.start()
         .done(function(error){})
         .fail(function(error){});
```

On client-side I get token like this:

```
 $.post("https://localhost:44302/token", { grant_type: "password", username: user.username, password: user.password})
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data && data.access_token) {
                    bearerToken = data.access_token; 
                }
            })
            .fail(function (xhr) {
             error('Wrong password or username.');
            });
```

So I saved token in bearerToken but how now I can pass this to server side?
In this code:

```
[HubName("chathub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
  ...
```

IsAuthenticated is false, and there no data in User.